# Projeto Maven + Spring MVC + JSP, como compartilhar arquivos de view?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

estou tentando ajustar uma estrutura de arquivos para começar um projeto grande, um ERP para ser mais exato. Hoje, existe uma boa parte dele feita em PHP de forma desordenada. Vamos adotar o Java Web (Maven + Spring MVC + JSP + Hibernate) para criar os próximos módulos e futuramente refazer os outros módulos. Dentro do que já foi estudado, estou com uma dúvida, provavelmente boba para vocês, mas para mim, ainda não achei o caminho.

Pensamos em criar um projeto para cada módulo (sistema) só que pode existir a possibilidade de um projeto ter que usar os recursos de outro projeto, em específico, partes da view. Como é possível controlar esta troca de recursos da view?

Sei que o Maven controla via multi-módulos as dependências e tals, mas como ficaria essa questão de, por exemplo, se eu tiver uma pasta com imagens no projeto A, e eu precisar de usá-las no projeto B sem precisar informar o caminho completo?

desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso.

## Colocar recursos dentro de um jar

Alguns frameworks (como o PrimeFaces e o GWT) fazem isso porque facilita o compartilhamento de recursos estáticos disponíveis no classpath.

Crie um projeto Maven para armazenar esses recursos em `java/main/resources`. Eles vão junto com o sistema em um jar e podem ser servidos para o *client* através de um Servlet.

O Spring MVC já faz isso automaticamente com a configuração:

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/"/>
```

Veja a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) para maiores detalhes.

## *War overlay*

Outra saída é criar um projeto Maven web (WAR) com os arquivos gerais e configurar o Maven War Plugin dos demais projetos fazer [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), mesclando os WAR's.

Isso funciona, pois já usei, mas confesso que pode ser meio confuso para configurar e deixar tudo funcionando perfeitamente, além de ser mais complicado de integrar com uma IDE.

## Recursos fora da aplicação

É possível configura um servidor web simples (como já mencionado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23416/227)) ou em uma aplicação Java web separada.

Você pode usar caminhos relativos à raiz do servidor, por exemplo: `/resources-app/images/image01.png`.

Obviamente isso pode ser um problema caso queira usar diferentes versões de projetos que usem diferentes Javascript's, CSS's e imagens.

Além disso, pode ser um problema caso o local dos resources seja diferente. Nesse caso, você pode criar uma configuração no `web.xml` em cada aplicação com o *base path* dos resources. Dessa forma, basta mudar um simples local para definir se as imagens vão estar em `/app/imagens` ou `http://192.162.0.1/images`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas ideias utluiz e rdeandrade. Vou tentar ver o que faço e qualquer depois eu posto aqui a solução que me foi mais adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer no caso, é um servido de arquivos estáticos e colocá-lo num servidor apenas com apache mesmo. É comum isso. Mas no caso se for apenas HTML, CSS, JS, Imagens e etc. Assim em todos os outros módulos basta você referências o servidor de mídias, que pode até ter o mesmo DNS do servidor da aplicação, ficando transparente na hora de fazera  requisição.